# Excel is copying percentages in thousands... why?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm copying stats for work from one spreadsheet to another, but the percentages show in thousands, where the decimal point seems to move (e.g. what should be 32% shows as 3235%).
One the sheet I'm copying from, it shows 32%, but the problem occurs on the sheet I'm pasting to.
How or why does this happen?
How can I fix it?

Formatting the cells, is the only thing I've tried, as I'm not sure what else to do.

(no programming code available as it's a copy/paste routine)

My expected result: it should paste as 32%
The actual result: it pastes as 3235%

Comment: It's hard to know if there is any error in your sheets without seeing the sheets. If possible kindly share the excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if you are copying percentage value or just value without percents. If you copy 32.35 instead of 32.35%, the result shown in another sheet with percentage format will be 3235%, because 32.35=3235%.

Answer (score 0):

I may be format issue as Ketzul mentioned above, to again convert into percentage format copy a cell contain value 100 and paste as divide. you can get the same value as the previous sheet. if you need exact answer, please share the file

Answer (score 0):

I have had this occur when using the % button in excel.

I have now developed the habit of expressing any number that I use in calculations as a value between 0 and 1 and working from there...

So for your 32.35% I would use 0.3235